# How to duplicate two specific rows and columns multiple times?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm which contains 2 textboxes and 1 combobox.

1. TxtboxDate;
2. ComboBoxName;
3. TxtBoxNumber;and
4. AddCommandButton

My excel table looks like this when I enter the following in my userform

(Row)                           (Column)
       A          B              C            D                    E
1     Date    Slip Number      Name    Vehicle Plate Number      Status
2  28-Jan-19 (given already)  Tom Tax     (has a formula)    (has a formula)
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

All I wanted only was, when I enter the number/value (Ex. "3") in textboxNumber in my UserForm, and then hit the AddCommandButton, it will copy the value I enter in TxtboxDate & ComboBoxName and paste it into 3 times.

How will I do that?

I pasted my code below and Please see attached picture for more info. Please help????

```
Private Sub cmdbutton12_Click()
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Fuels_Slips_Issued")
  Dim rngNullString
  'find first empty row in database

   Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("A"), ws.Columns("A")).Find("")
     If rngNullString.Row < ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Then
        Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("A"), ws.Columns("A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    End If
   iRow = rngNullString.Row

  ' iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  ' SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
  'check for Name number
   If Trim(Me.tb1.Value) = "" Then
   Me.tb1.SetFocus
   MsgBox "Please complete the FORM"
   Exit Sub
 End If

 'copy the data to the database
  ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.tb1.Value
  ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.cmb_issued.Value


  MsgBox "Successfully! Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"

  'clear the data
   Me.tb1.Value = ""
   Me.cmb_issued = ""
   Me.tb1.SetFocus

   Worksheets("Fuels_Slips_Issued").Activate
 End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the process of copying the data into the table, and include that as part of your row to change. Modify your code as such:

```
'copy the data to the database
Dim c As Long 'starts as zero

Do
    ws.Cells(iRow + c, 1).Value = Me.tb1.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow + c, 3).Value = Me.cmb_issued.Value
    c = c + 1

Loop Until c = Me.TxtBoxNumber
```

You also might want to make sure that the user enters an integer on the command-click. Hope that works.

Comment: WOW! You are great sir. you solve my problem within an hour only. Thank you very much sir.